# We have an urn with 20 red, 10 black and 15 green balls. We take a sample of 30, without replacement, with order.

Tags: probability

Find the probability that the 3rd, 10th and 23rd picks are of different colors.

I think I can use symmetry to say that it doesn't matter that it's the 3rd, 10th, or 23rd, as I can just treat it as the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd picks.  I'm a stuck on the different colored balls though.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the answer as simple as $\frac{20\cdot10\cdot15}{45\cdot44\cdot43}\cdot3!\approx21\%$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in stating that it can be looked at as picking $3$ balls.

Picking $3$ balls out of $45$ can be done on $\binom{45}{3}=14190$
ways.

Picking $3$ balls out of $45$ under the extra condition that they
are of different color can be done here on $20\times10\times15=3000$
ways. A red ball must be picked ($20$ possibilities) a black ball must be picked ($10$ possibilities) and a green ball must be picked ($15$ possibilities)

That results in a probability of $\frac{3000}{14190}$ of picking $3$ balls of different color.

Comment: Funny, I got exactly half of that.

Comment: @barakmanos I think your answer is correct and will try to find my mistake.

Comment: @barakmanos Fixed now. Thank you (how on earth could I believe that $2\times1\times1.5=6$??? Maybe my age).

Comment: You've fixed quite a few of mine in the past, so I guess I owe you one...